# How can I run a Spark structured streaming job for a certain time?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I want to schedule a Spark structured streaming job each day. The Job itself must run for a certain number of hours and then stop. So, how can I specify such time duration?

Comment: Do you want to do it from within the streaming app itself? did you think about providing a timeout for the task from the scheduler (airflow) for example? the disadvantage in this case that the shutdown won't be graceful but if you don't care about it, it can be a simple solution.

Comment: I can use a scheduler. Not Airflow though but Databricks. Disgraceful shutdown is also fine.

Comment: And the databricks scheduler doesn't have an option for timouting the task?

Comment: It does, you can let your Databricks job timeout

Answer (score 4):

You need to schedule job with databricks scheduler once a day and then in the code add a timeout to your query:

```
query = (df.writeStream...)

  query.awaitTermination(timeoutInSeconds)
  query.stop()
```